# IOS Drag & Drop With Scaling

Tags: ios, drag-and-drop

I have a UIView subclass, containing several subviews, that I want to drag & drop into one of several other UIViews which are contained in a UICollectionView.  When the drag begins, I'd like to scale the dragged view from its current size to something smaller for the duration of the drag (the original is too large to conveniently allow selection of the drop target without first scaling it down)  So far, I have this:

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self.superview bringSubviewToFront:self];
    self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.3f, 0.3f);
    startLocation = ([[touches anyObject] locationInView:self]);
    startLocation = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(startLocation, self.transform);
}

- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{  
    CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
    float dx = pt.x - startLocation.x;
    float dy = pt.y - startLocation.y;
    CGPoint newCenter = CGPointApplyAffineTransform (CGPointMake(self.center.x + dx, self.center.y + dy), self.transform);
    self.center = newCenter;
}
```

This is a start, as it scales the dragged UIView as I want it to, and will allow me to drag it; however, the dragged UIView does not move directly with the mouse pointer (I'm running on the simulator).  When the image is near the upper-left corner of the simulator screen, the mouse pointer & dragged view are together; but as I move away from the upper right corner of the screen, the view no longer moves directly with the mouse pointer; the mouse pointer seems to move at about a 2:1 ratio to the movement of the dragged UIView.

A secondary issue is that when the dragging ends, if the item isn't dropped, I need to return the UIView to its original scale before reattaching it to its superview, and haven't quite figured out how to do that.

Appreciate any help, including suggestions about a better approach if I'm totally off track here. (I know there is other stuff to be done on isolating the drop target and dropping, but I'm thinking I know what needs to be done there).

Thanks for any guidance.

regex

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I got the answer & thought I should post here in case anyone else needs it.  Thanks for the earlier reply.  I came across the following article:

[How to move a UIImageView after applying CGAffineTransformRotate to it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859731/how-to-move-a-uiimageview-after-applying-cgaffinetransformrotate-to-it)

and this brought me to the following solution.  In my original code I was applying the transform to the start location, but I was not applying it to the touch point.  So, here's what I ended up with that solved the problem:

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self.superview bringSubviewToFront:self];
    self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.2f, 0.2f);
    startLocation = ([[touches anyObject] locationInView:self]);
    startLocation = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(startLocation, self.transform);
}

- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
    if (!CGAffineTransformIsIdentity(self.transform))
        pt = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(pt, self.transform);
    float dx = pt.x - startLocation.x;
    float dy = pt.y - startLocation.y;
    CGPoint newCenter = CGPointMake(self.center.x + dx, self.center.y + dy);
    self.center = newCenter;
}
```

So, the transform needed to be applied to the touch point if and only if a transform has been applied to the UIView.  I had, at one point, applied the transform to the touch point, but without the conditional -- in that instance, the entire drag operation got off to a bad start because the transform was applied to the touch point possibly before the point had even been moved.  Anyway, the code above seems to have resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the touchesmoved is still using the old size. As a suggestion I would first start without resizing and just implement drag and drop.

When drag and drop is working implement the resizing. First for start dragging and then for drop. Do it in steps this will get you a better feeling off what you are trying to achieve.

Regarding the 2:1 ratio I have a feeling it is regarding the transform you didn't resize the view in total but I can be wrong. But make sure you make the drag view smaller and the middle is pointing to you drag point.

Some references that may help are:

http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/simple-drag-and-drop-on-iphone/
http://bynomial.com/blog/?p=77

Comment: Okay, I got it, and I thought I'd post the code I ended up with in case someone else needs it.  I found another article with a similar problem here: